# Edit Views in Laravel 4

Tags: view, laravel, edit, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Being new to Laravel 4, I'd like your advice on something please.

I'm creating an edit view for the edit method of a resource controller, and was wondering how you handle getting the correct data from the database for that record in to the form controls, such as select boxes and inputs etc?

Can anyone give me any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read L4 docs first http://four.laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding

> Often, you will want to populate a form based on the contents of a
>   model. To do so, use the Form::model method:
>
> ```php
> echo Form::model($user, array('route' => 'user.update'))
> ```

Comment: I know that example comes straight from the docs, but you probably want to provide the `$user->id` to the `user.update` route too.

Comment: Not sure if it's needed or not, but I struggled a bit on the syntax to do that with the Form::model method so hopefully this will save you a minute. `echo Form::model($user, array('route'=>array('blogs.update',$user->id), 'method'=>'POST'))`